# how to get keyboard height for portrait and landscape in IPhone and IPad

Tags: ios, keyboard, orientation, landscape-portrait

I want to handle keyboard notifications to move textfield up and down on tap of it in portrait as well as landscape ..how to get the height of keyboard in portrait and landscape to achieve this?

Comment: r u try in ios7 or ios8

Comment: gd question my friend,

Comment: I want it to work in both ios7 and ios8

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)note {
      NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
      CGSize _kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
      float kbHeight = _kbSize.width > _kbSize.height ? _kbSize.height : _kbSize.width;
}
```

it will work in all the cases.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: iOS 7 & iOS 8 behave differently, but this solution fixes it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find Height of keyboard using following code.

```
// Works in both portrait and landscape mode
CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
kbRect = [self.view convertRect:kbRect toView:nil];

CGSize kbSize = kbRect.size;


NSLog(@"Keyboard Height: %f Width: %f", kbSize.height, kbSize.width);
```